# NaN output in Javascript from a class function

Tags: javascript, class, nan

I need to solve the following problem:

Create class Intern with next fields:
Name(String)
Surname(String)
laziness(number from 20 to 50)
Curiosity (number from 0 to 100)
Skill (number from 0 to 100)
Irresponsibility (float number from 0.0 to 1.0)
For this class create method that calculate “mark” for intern, that is calculated by formula(in the code)
It looks simple, but when I run it, the output is NaN. Could somebody help please?

```
class Intern {
    constructor(name, surname, laziness, curiosity, skill, irresponsibility) {
        this.name = name
        this.surname = surname
        if (laziness <= 50 && laziness >= 20) {
            this.laziness = laziness
        } else {
            this.laziness = 0
        }

        if (curiosity <= 100 && curiosity >= 0) {
            this.curiosity = curiosity
        }
        if (skill <= 100 && skill >= 0) {
            this.skill = skill
        }
        if (irresponsibility <= 0 && irresponsibility >= 1) {
            this.irresponsibility = irresponsibility
        }
    }

    getMark() {
        let mark = (((this.skill + this.curiosity) * (1.5 - this.irresponsability)) / (this.laziness * 0.25));
        return mark
    }
}
```

Comment: try a `console.log(this);` inside the `getMark()` function and see/confirm that skill, curiosity, irresponsability and laziness all got values.

Comment: You need to correct the property name and provide a default value for out of range properties like you did with laziness.

Comment: Did you proofread your code before posting? Sometimes rereading the code in an editor that you don't develop in can help highlight obvious mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelled the `irresponsibility` variable in the `getMark()` method, and the `if` statement in your constructor for it will never be true:

```js
if (irresponsibility <=0 && irresponsibility >=1)
```

I think you were meaning to say:

```js
if (irresponsibility >=0 && irresponsibility >=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very sorry for the stupid question. But I stayed all day long and re-read it and didn't notice it!!! OMG, indeed corrected the if. Thank you again! Sometimes happens that the mistake is obvious but you didn't find it, and I am novice to OOP. so sorry about the stupid question.

Comment: Haha don't worry about it :)